# Definition of finite dimensional decomposition of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The question is in the title.

> What is the definition of finite dimensional decomposition of Banach space?

I have been looking around for a while and can't find anything!
Thanks

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: In a paper by Odell. Titled  'A UNIVERSAL REFLEXIVE SPACE FOR THE CLASS OF UNIFORMLY CONVEX BANACH SPACES'

Answer (score 2):

> Let $X$ be a Banach space. A sequence $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of finite-dimensional subspaces of $X$ is called a finite-dimensional decomposition of $X$ if every $x\in X$ has a unique representation of the form $x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ with $x_n\in X_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

This is Definition 4.31 on page 198 of [Banach Space Theory: The Basis for Linear and Nonlinear Analysis](https://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C) by Marián Fabian, Petr Habala, Petr Hájek, Vicente Montesinos, Václav Zizler.